# How to close popup window based on url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am opening pop window someurl.aspx. after processing redirect to parent url. But I need to close if the window locate parent url.

```
 function openNewWin(url) {
        window.location = '../../Portal/Billing/BillGeneration.aspx';
        var newwindow = window.open(url, 'popuprpt', 'width=940,height=700,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=10,top=5');

        var isPopup = (window.location.href == window.opener.location.href);
        if (isPopup == true) {
            newwindow.close();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

But Its not working. How to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of the newly open window. It will work only if you are checking for the same domain documents, but in your case it should work:

```
var wn = window.open(.....);

//!!! you also need to wait till the window is opened and loaded.
setTimeout(function(){
    try{
        if( document.location.href === wn.document.location.href ){
           // same url
        }
    }catch(ex){ 
        console.log(ex) 
    }
}, 2000 );
```

This code will run the check after 2 seconds